# Prove that $P[x] + \langle x \rangle$ is a prime ideal of $R[x].$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, maximal-and-prime-ideals, polynomial-rings

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and $P$ be a prime ideal of $R.$ Consider the polynomial ring $R[x]$ and let $P[x]$ be the ideal of $R[x]$ consisting of polynomials whose co-efficients all belong to $P.$ Show that the ideal $$P[x] + \langle x \rangle : = \left \{f(x) + x g(x)\ \big |\ f(x) \in P[x],g(x) \in R[x] \right \}$$ is a prime ideal of $R[x].$

**My attempt** $:$ What I first observe is that $$f(x) \in P[x] + \langle x \rangle \iff f(0) \in P.$$ Because if $f$ is a zero polynomial then we are through. Otherwise we can write $f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_k x^k,$ where $a_1,a_2, \cdots, a_n \in R$ and $a_n \neq 0.$ But then $$f(x) = a_0 + x \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_k x^{k-1} = f(0) + x \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_k x^{k-1}.$$ So $f(x) \in P[x] + \langle x \rangle \iff f(0) \in P[x] \iff f(0) \in P,$ which proves our claim.

Now let $A(x), B(x) \in R[x]$ such that $A(x) B(x) \in P[x] + \langle x \rangle.$ Then there exist $f(x) \in P[x]$ and $g(x) \in R[x]$ such that $A(x) B(x) = f(x) + x g(x).$ But then $A(0) B(0) = f(0).$ Since $f(x) \in P[x]$ we have $f(0) \in P.$ Hence $A(0) B(0) \in P.$ Since $P$ was a prime ideal of $R$ it follows that either $A(0) \in P$ or $B(0) \in P.$ But then by our previous observation we conclude that either $A(x) \in P[x] + \langle x \rangle$ or $B(x) \in P[x] + \langle x \rangle.$ This shows that $P[x] + \langle x \rangle$ is a prime ideal of $R[x].$

**QED**

Does my proof hold good? Please verify it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is correct for me

Comment: @Anacardium Your proof is essentially correct (its presentation could be improved though). A more elegant manner to prove this result is to consider the composition of the canonical surjections $A[X] \to (A/P)[X] \to A/P$, the first one being the canonical extension to polynomial rings of the canonical surjection $A \to A/P$ and the second being the map of evaluation at $0_{A/P}$. As the composition of two surjective ring morphisms, this map is itself a surjective ring morphism whose kernel is precisely $K＝P[X]＋(X)$. Since the quotient $A/P$ is a domain, the quotient $A[X]/K$ also must be one.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ it's a brilliant idea. Thanks for sharing your idea.+1

Comment: @Glad to know you found it instructive. Indeed, in many cases when working with - loosely speaking - abstract mathematical structures, one finds it easy to prove that a given subset of the support set of the ambient structure (whether an algebraic structure, a topological space, a manifold etc) is naturally a substructure by virtue of it occurring as the preimage through a particular morphism of a particular substructure of the target structure (target of the morphism in question, that is).